# REST is returning '↵'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, rest

I have a problem when returning REST spaces for a textarea from a list.

To get the information the REST is returning '↵' instead of space.

Need to know how I change this symbol '↵' for space.

Example: Image Erro: 
[image]

Image Correct: 
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the request and one of your result objects?

Comment: are you sure it's not a line break?

Comment: Well, I try to give a space in textarea but the rest returns the symbol. Check out the images below: Correct: http://i.imgur.com/cHE7vfU.png. Error: http://i.imgur.com/U4GiG2A.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that string contains carriage return character `↵`  in JSON result, in that case you could replace a carriage return character with a `<br>` using the following function:

```
function escapeCRLF(value) 
{
    return value.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");  
}
```

**Example**

Assume the following function is used for retrieving ListItem resource:

```
function getListItem(webUrl, listName,listItemId, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then the following code demonstrate how to return escaped `Description` property:

```
getListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,listTitle,1,
function(data){
    var description = escapeCRLF(data.Description);
},function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

### References

[Special Symbols and Math Symbols in HTML and JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm)